# Type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to use application settings in my project.

When I try the following line of code in the project, I get an error.

`TransferLogs.Properties.Settings.Default.ValleyLastRun = timeNow;`

The resulting error is:

> The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'Williams.TransferLogs' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have the setting "ValleyLastRun" defined as a DateTime on my Project->Properties->Settings page. I don't know why I can't reference the setting in my project.

Here's the solution window:

[image]

Comment: have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your project solution explorer window with references showing, and both the parent code that houses that `ValleyLastRun` as well as the code that uses it. What we're looking for is whether the namespace is correct, if the project actually holds a reference to the project, what type of reference it is (GAC'd, or project reference) and if you're setting it up correctly.  You may also want to clean and rebuild and see if that solves the problem.  Also, what type of project is it?

Comment: If properties is a class, is it set to be public?

Comment: Tried a clean build, but no go. It's a WinForms project.

Comment: It's probably an accessibility issue. `Properties` is internal, so your class may not be able to "see" it.

Comment: @GavinCoates `Properties` is auto-generated when you add a `Settings.settings` file.

Comment: Where did "Williams" come from?  Do you have a class named TransferLogs, thus clashing with the project's default name space, also TransferLogs?  Try global::TransferLogs.Properties

Comment: Williams is a common namespace I use for applications developed for my company. The namespace for "frmTransferLogs" is Williams.TransferLogs. I tried adding "global::" and it "sees" my settings now. It just gives me an error about it being read only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is related to your resource file. Per default the settings are generated as internal. You can change that in the dropdown box above the settings.

There is sometimes a problem with the constructor of this class because it remains internal. You can change that manually but after every edit of the Settings it will be reset to internal.

Comment: Made my day, not to believe - your answer is >7 years old, but still same problems...

Answer (score 14):

This issue can also crop up if you've changed the namespace.

Comment: And also note that changing the namespace can entail merely changing the case of the namespace or some part of the namespace. So say you change the case of the namespace in project settings then change the access modifier of a project file like Properties it will then pick up the newly "cased" namespace... but if all your forms are referencing an say the previously UPPER cased namespace and you've changed the project namespace to ProperCase, they will all fail to find the "new" project properties or resources file because it will be auto generated with the ProperCase.

Comment: This was my problem: I had changed my Program.cs namespace from Foo to Bar.Foo without changing it in the project properties. The Settings.Designer.cs class was of course generated in the namespace Foo, which unsurprisingly prevented me from referencing it from Program.cs.

Comment: can also be caused by inconsistency of namespace in the resx and designer.cs file - the resx file got changed and not regenerated or the designer file got changed accidentally

Answer (score 8):

Like user1959018, I also faced this error message although for different reasons than the OP, and I'll post what I finally found my problem and solution to be in case it helps others.

In the project's Properties folder there should be (at least) two files, Resources.resx and Resources.Designer.cs. In my case the Resources.Designer.cs file was somehow no longer included in the project. This can be fixed by editing (or restoring an old copy of) the .csproj file, or by using Visual Studio's Solution Explorer to "show all files" and then right-click on Resources.Designer.cs and select "Include in project".

And credit where credit is due, I found this solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/ebeca7a8-c7a3-4cb6-a40e-89c5fdb70c82
in the answer by NJLASSI.

EDIT:

Just re-including the Resources.Designer.cs file in the project is not a good solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270971/visual-studio-type-or-namespace-name-properties-does-not-exist/16270972) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this error because my Settings.settings file vanished after a svn update (not the solution to this case but may help others).

To fix go to project properties, settings and click the link to create a settings file. After that it magically generates the properties used in the project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem that my project properties did not contain the correct namespace (-> Application) which I used all over the application. Changing the default namespace helped to let me access resources and settings inside classes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different error (but similar). When I checked for Resources.Designer.cs it wasn't there. (I was upgrading to a VS2013 solution and moving to Team Foundation VC)

Right-clicking on Resources.resx and using "Run custom tool" built Resources.Designer.cs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you don't have a Properties section of your application.  If you right click the project in solution explorer and choose to create a new settings file, you can can access it via Settings1."yourinfo".  Settings1 and yourinfo change depending on what you named your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing "internal" in my Resources class definition. However, as **slfan** said, it comes back to "internal" after every edit you make. So be sure to check that out first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I changed the namespace of a class library.  When you add a settings file, it creates a class that uses the namespace (in Settings.cs - 
"namespace YourNameSpace.Properties{....".  When I renamed my namespace, it could not find the .Properties namespace because i spelled it different.
New namespace "namespace YourRenamedNameSpace"  so there was no "YourRenamedNameSpace.Properties"   In Setting.cs, I just corrected the namespace to "namespace YourRenamedNameSpace.Properties{...." and Properties.Settings was available within the namespace again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason whenever I edit settings.settings, it changes the namespace in the settings files.
So to fix this I had to do the following two things.
Right click settings.cs , view code and update the namespace at the top of the document to match that in the project >properties >application.
Secondly I then had to click the little arrow next to settings.settings in the solution Explorer to expand it, and then right click settings.designer.CS.
Within this file I have to also update the namespace.
I think because this solution was originally converted from Visual Basic to c#, it somehow has stored the old namespace, and keeps defaulting back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a new dummy setting as follows:

[image: dummy setting]

then clicking the Save button. All errors saying "the name 'properties' does not exist in the current context" disappeared.